# Organic groups chat - what are my options?

Tags: organic-groups

I have several organic groups which has members added. I want to a chat system that allows members within the same group to communicate amongst each other.

What modules can i do to achieve this? what are my options? I am running drupal 6.

Answer (score 1):

I think [DrupalChat](http://drupal.org/project/drupalchat) might integrate with Organic Groups. According to [Issue#871238](http://drupal.org/node/871238) the patch in [comment#2](http://drupal.org/node/871238#comment-4521744) adds this functionality.

The patch looks like it was committed to the dev branch on January 21, 2012. With the release dates of the beta11 version and the latest dev version, it looks like it might already be in those respective releases. If not, try the patch mentioned above.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your comment. I have looked at the patch and plugin and it does work - it restricts visible members to only group members. The issue is, if all members want to chat to each other, they would need to private message each other.Are you aware of any other alternatives?

Comment: What is the alternative for d8?

Comment: @Daniela [DrupalChat](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalchat) has a beta version for D8. A full release chat module for D8 is [Rocket.Chat](https://www.drupal.org/project/rocket_chat)

Comment: @gbrands but none of them are integrated with og.

Comment: Also, drupal chat version is from 2017.